# Find all select boxes with id or name starting with a specific string

Tags: jquery

I am trying to push all select elements starting with specific id or name and tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
var IDs = [];
$("#dynamic_field [id^='product_id']").find("select").each(function(){ IDs.push(this.id); });
alert(IDs.length);
```

If I don't specify the specific select id or name it works:

```
var IDs = [];
$("#dynamic_field").find("select").each(function(){ IDs.push(this.id); });
    alert(IDs.length);
```

Any help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to get `select` tag within `select` tag, remove the find part since its already contains collection of `select` tags(assuming elements with id prefix `product_id` are select tags). If there are other elements with id prefix `product_id` then combine `select` with the attribute starts with selector.

```
var IDs = [];
$("#dynamic_field select[id^='product_id']").each(function(){ IDs.push(this.id); });
alert(IDs.length);
```

---

You can use jQuery [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method to generate the array where use [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method to convert jQuery collection to array.

```
var IDs = $("#dynamic_field select[id^='product_id']").map(function(){ return this.id; }).get();
```

or using [`jQuery.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) method.

```
var IDs = $.map($("#dynamic_field select[id^='product_id']"), ele => ele.id);
```